# Every IDE falls into disassembly mode during debugging

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, disassembly

I have installed Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) recently, then QtCreator. Every time when I try to debug my C program in it, it falls into disassembly mode, it means when I try to step into, or even step over, it opens a file "Disassasembly(...)" and navigates in this file. It happens not only for standard functions like malloc (which source code I don't have), but also for my own functions. I thought it's because of the IDE, and installed NetBeans - and I have exactly the same problem in it.

Some example:

[it is shown after stepping over my function, and this function is just the beginning of my program, but the program ends after this screen] - edit: sorry I had to remove this file, because I can post only 2 links..

Another problem is when even for a short moment it navigates on my code (not on disassembly), it executes lines which contains documentation, and gets out to the body of another fuction, which isn't called by me at all(!) It looks like a mess...

So, I think it might be some problem with GDB, but I have no idea how to solve it. Could you help me?

GDB v. 7.11.1
gcc v. 5.4.0
NetBeans v. 8.2

EDIT: It became really weird. Today, when I tried to debug it once again, without any changes in code nor settings, the debugger started to behave *almost* normally, it means, that it steps through my code correctly now. The only moment, when it falls into dissasembly mode, is the end of my program, when last instruction has executed and it should end. This screens should help:

[(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5zw6.png)
[(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z2PZ.png)

EDIT2: Ok, maybe it is quite normal now. But I still have no idea, what was wrong, and what solved the problem. I hope that it won't come back :)

Comment: It seems you debug optimized C++ code.

Comment: may be code is not compatible with the binary you are running. Old binary new code.

Comment: Is the assembly language function that the debugger stumbles into always __libc_start_main, or is it sometimes something else?

Comment: Can you switch to the gdb interaction window in your IDE and see if either of the following two commands  print `on`? `show backtrace past-main` and `show backtrace past-entry` .

Comment: @SergeiKurenkov : i'm compiling only with -d flag, and neither -O2 nor -O3.

Comment: @ThePhilomath I'm building the binary just before debugging - so it's compatible for sure.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : it used to stumble into my own function too. I can't find a possibility to use gdb commands in NetBeans.

Comment: See my edit, because the problem suddenly almost dissappeared..

Comment: Now that I see the highlighted line in __libc_start_main, it looks like you're just stepping through your program after the point at which `main` has returned, So what that window shows is that the C startup code is about to call `exit` for you.